# Update div string contents using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that exists only in memory that may contain zero or more images. I'm trying the change the src of thouse images using JQuery find, the problem is that even though i manager to set the src of each img the the content of the div remains unchanged.

```
    function contentWithReplacedImages(divContent){
    console.log(divContent);//I get <div class='editable singleColumnElement'><p>asdasd ad a dasd ad<br/></p><p><img/> <br/></p></div>
    $(divContent).find("img").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr({
            'src':"imgSrc"
        });
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));//I get "imgSrc"
    });

    console.log(divContent); //divContent remains unchanged.

}
```

Comment: It's part of a bigger script, the function is called i promise you that, but this is the only part that is not working. Right now i'm testing it using Firefox scratchpad

Comment: Can you improve your formatting and your question a little bit by describing the context for example. That could help us too understand and answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are returning the divContent string; so maybe, the changes you make only exist inside of the contentWithReplacedImages function itself.  Try assigning the contents of the divContent to a new variable, and returning that variable to another string variable, ex `var myNewString = contentWithReplacedImages(divContent);`

Comment: You're creating a new element with the contents of divContent, not doing a search and replace on the string itself.

Comment: @Archer sorry pretty new to javascript and Jquery could you please elaboreate, i'm watching the `console.log(divContent);` of my function and it's the same as my input

Comment: I've added some script in an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a new element...

```
$(divContent)
```

You then find the images within that new element and change the src attribute.  You have not at any point changed `divContent` itself.

Try this...

```
function contentWithReplacedImages(divContent){
    console.log(divContent);
    var $divContent = $(divContent);
    $divContent.find("img").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr({
            'src':"imgSrc"
        });
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));
    });
    divContent = $divContent.html();
    console.log(divContent);
}

contentWithReplacedImages("<div class='editable singleColumnElement'><p>asdasd ad a dasd ad<br/></p><p><img/> <br/></p></div>");
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much, i'll mark it as the correct answer in a few minutes, can't just yet. Has no idea it creats a new object

Answer (score 5):

You've altered `$(divContent)` (jQuery object), but at the end you're checking the contents of the original `divContent` (html string).

Since `divContent` isn't actually part of the DOM, you're not saving your changes anywhere.

Try setting a new variable:

```
function contentWithReplacedImages(divContent) {
     var $temp = $(divContent); // jQuery object
     $temp.find("img").each(function (i,el) {
         $(el).attr({
             'src': "imgSrc.jpg"
         }); // $temp is modified in place
     });    
     console.log($temp.html()); // displays the modified string 
 }
```